# Unable to run npm install successfully due to unmet peer dependencies

Tags: json, node.js, gruntjs

I have `package.json` file in which following devDependencies are mentioned:

```
"devDependencies": {
    "bower": "^1.7.7",
    "connect-ssi": "^1.1.0",
    "grunt": "~0.4.5",
    "grunt-contrib-compass": "^1.1.0",
    "grunt-contrib-concat": "~0.4.0",
    "grunt-contrib-connect": "^0.11.2",
    "grunt-contrib-handlebars": "^0.11.0",
    "grunt-contrib-jshint": "~0.10.0",
    "grunt-contrib-qunit": "~0.5.2",
    "grunt-contrib-sass": "^0.9.2",
    "grunt-contrib-uglify": "~0.5.0",
    "grunt-contrib-watch": "~0.6.1",
    "grunt-jsdoc": "^1.1.0",
    "karma": "^0.13.22",
    "karma-jasmine": "^0.3.7"
  }
```

Now when I run `npm install` it gives me following errors:

> UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY jasmine-core@*
>   npm WARN EPEERINVALID karma-jasmine@0.3.8 requires a peer of jasmine-core@* but none was installed.
>   npm WARN EPACKAGEJSON hirebuddy-prototype@0.0.1 No repository field.

`hirebuddy-prototype` is the name in the package.json.

Will running `npm install` install all the dependencies mentioned in the package.json or do I need to install `jasmine-core` and `karma-jasmine` separately?

Answer (score 6):

This is a weakness in karma-jasmine. In its package.json, `jasmine-core` is listed as a peerDependency, and NPM 3 no longer installs these automatically. So you have to add `jasmine-core` in your own package.json. So just `npm install jasmine-core --save-dev`, and cross your fingers that the latest version is compatible. It should be.

Info: http://blog.npmjs.org/post/110924823920/npm-weekly-5

Comment: Thanks @dannyjolie, now its not showing the error for jasmine-core and karma-jasmine but i have another concern: Now when i run 'grunt' command it throws error:
Running "compass:dist" (compass) task
Warning: not found: compass Use --force to continue.

I have "grunt-contrib-compass dependency" in my package.json and the same folder is also showing up in the node_modules.I have gruntfile.js and a compass task in it and i am providing plugin:

 grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-compass') with taskrunner:
grunt.registerTask('default', ['connect:development', 'compass','watch']).

Comment: @ApaarBhatnagar It's all in the documentation: https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-compass Quote: "This task requires you to have Ruby, Sass, and Compass >=1.0.1 installed."